# Сортировка вектора структуру по определенному полю

Tags: c++

У меня есть структура:

```
struct Abonent {
private:
    struct FIO
    {
        string surname;//фамилия
        string name;//имя
        string midname;//отчество
    };
    FIO currentFIO;
    string phone;
    int year;//Год
    string current_plane;//Текущий тарифный план
public:
    Abonent() {}
    Abonent(string parsurname, string parname, string parmidname, string
        parphone, int paryear, string parplane) {}
#pragma region Getters/Setters
    string GetSurname();  //Получить фамилию
    void SetSurname(string surname); //Установить фамилию
    string GetName();        //Получить имя
    void SetName(string name); //Установить имя
    string GetMidName(); //Получить отчество
    void SetMidName(string midname);//Установить отчество
    int GetYear();       //Получить год
    void* GetYearMemory();  //Получить адрес переменной хранящей год
    void SetYear(int year);  //Установить год
    string GetPhone();  //Получить телефон
    void SetPhone(string phone);  //Установить телефон
    string GetPlane();   //Получить план
    void SetPlane(string plane);  //Установить план
};
```

На основе этой структуры я создаю вектор. И мне нужно отсортировать по полю `Year`. Много времени на это потратил и никак не получилось написать функцию по сортировке. Тут простая функция по сравнению как для массивов  не работает. Т.е. нужна простая сортировка. Функция sort тоже не дает необходимых результатов

Answer (score 2):

Во первых все геттеры  должны обозначаться как константные(они не модифицируют обьект), чтобы обеспечить возможность их вызова и для константных обьектов. И лучше определить геттеры прямо в структуре(для автоматического встривания). Типа: `int GetYear() const { return year;}`

Чтобы сортировать обьекты, для них должен быть определен `оператор <` .  Значит, определите его или в структуре или вне структуры:

```
bool operator<(const Abonent& a1, const Abonent& a2)
{
    return a1.GetYear() < a2.GetYear();
}
```

Если вам может понадобиться и сортировка по другим критериям, то тогда нужно определять соответствующие компараторы.

**UPDATE:** Вот пример сортировки:

```
void SortYear(vector<Abonent>& abonents) {
      std::sort(abonents.begin(), abonents.end());
}
```

std::sort по умолчанию сортирует сравнивая элементы по `оператору <` Вы же, имея только этот оператор, if(a1 > a2)  можете выразить так: `if(!(a1 < a2))` , т.е. если не меньше... или, если не нужно выполнить при равенстве, то  нужно не забывать, что:  `если(a2 < a1)`  значит `a1 > a2`

Comment: Т.е. как я вижу эту перегрузку. Я беру 2 вектора и делаю сравнение:
if(a1>a2)
{ ... } и я сравниваю эти два вектора по полям Year?

Comment: Нет, вы берете один вектор, а чтобы сортировать вектор, нужно его элементы сравнивать. Есть  много  альгоритмов для сортировки, но все они сравнивают элементы, чтобы их расставить по порядку

Comment: хм, я перегрузил оператор и запихнул в функцию sort. При выводе vector все осталось на прежних местах. Когда я попытался вручную это сделать у меня выбивало ошибку. Я пытался сделать так:
void IEmployer::SortYear(vector<Abonent>* abonents)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < (*abonents).size(); i++)
  {
   for (int j = 0; j < (*abonents).size(); j++)
   {
    if ((*abonents)[i].GetYear() > (*abonents)[j].GetYear())
    {
     abonents[i].swap(abonents[j]);
    }
   }
  }
 
}. Однако у меня выбивает ошибку. Я думаю ошибка в том что я пытаюсь поменять указатели элементов вектора и не выходит.